# Why flutter version difference

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sdk, version

I am not getting here it says the current **flutter SDK** version is **2.0.2** but when I go on a **terminal** and search **flutter --version** it says Flutter **2.8.1** see below picture

[image]

**See** this pic why is it? in the above pic it says the flutter SDK version is **2.0.2** and in the below pic it says **2.8.1** ,Pls guide why this **difference**

[image]

Comment: You have multiple Flutter installations on your machine. In your first screenshots, it is your IDE which have a setting for where your Flutter installation are placed on your computer. In your second screenshot, you are using the PATH variable on your system to determine what Flutter it should use.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot, it was a great help I could not figure out earlier

Comment: Great. I have made an answer you can accept. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very likely to have two different versions of Flutter installed on your computer. This is possible because your IDE has its own setting to know where it should look for Flutter SDK which is what is used in your first screenshot.

In your second screenshot, you are running the `flutter` command in a terminal. To resolve what `flutter` means, it uses your PATH environment variable to search for an executable matching your command name.

So my guess is that your IDE and PATH environment variable points to two different Flutter installations on your computer.

Comment: so how do you solve it ?  while using CMD, it shows my latest flutter version. but inside anroid studio terminal it shows old version.

Comment: @SaadMansoor Go into the settings in Android Studio for Flutter and change the directory where it finds your Flutter installation. It might be a project setting or plugin setting. If you cannot find it, please post a new question since this one is already considered solved.